# How to increase the count of one column given the value of another?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to generate the value `caseid` across a very large dataset. I would like the `caseid` variable to do two things: (1) increase by `1` when `y = 1`. Importantly, `caseid`'s value should increase in the row *after* `y = 1` is observed, and (2) increase by `1` when `case` changes in value, i.e., from `A` to `B`.

Example data is below:

```
case = pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 
                  'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 
                  'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'])
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 0, 0, 
               0, 1, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 1, 0])
year = [2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 
        2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,
        2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
caseid = pd.Series([1, 1, 2, 2,
                    3, 3, 4, 4,
                    5, 5, 5, 6])
dict = {'case': case, 'y': y, 'year': year, 'caseid' : caseid}  
df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 

   case  y  year  caseid
0     A  0  2016       1
1     A  1  2017       1
2     A  0  2018       2
3     A  0  2019       2
4     B  0  2016       3
5     B  1  2017       3
6     B  0  2018       4
7     B  0  2019       4
8     C  0  2016       5
9     C  0  2017       5
10    C  1  2018       5
11    C  0  2019       6
```

I would greatly appreciate your generous help!

Comment: `df['case_id'] = (~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1).cumsum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `boolean mask` along with [`DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df['case_id'] = (~df['case'].eq(df['case'].shift(1).fillna(df.loc[0,'case'])) | 
                  df['y'].shift(1).fillna(0)).cumsum()+1

print(df)
   case  y  year  caseid
0     A  0  2016       1
1     A  1  2017       1
2     A  0  2018       2
3     A  0  2019       2
4     B  0  2016       3
5     B  1  2017       3
6     B  0  2018       4
7     B  0  2019       4
8     C  0  2016       5
9     C  0  2017       5
10    C  1  2018       5
11    C  0  2019       6
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

`df['case_id'] = ((~(df.case == df.case.shift())) | (df.y.shift()==1)).cumsum()`

Credits: @Quang Hoang (Only a bracket missing.)